# loop through JSON response gives undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This the JSON response

```
{
"phweb":{
  "cpu":"34.8",
  "ram":"30.5",
  "hdd":"42.9",
  "osup":"2 days, 20 hours, 45 minutes and 28 seconds",
  "osstat":"0",
  "apachestat":"0",
  "apacheup":"32 days, 23 hours, 49 minutes and 13 seconds",
  "sqlstat":"0",
  "sqlup":"13305410"
},
"phdbm":{
  "cpu":"14.7",
  "ram":"10.8",
  "hdd":"23.7",
  "osup":"2 days, 20 hours, 46 minutes and 15 seconds",
  "osstat":"0",
  "apachestat":"0",
  "apacheup":"103 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 53 seconds",
  "sqlstat":"0",
  "sqlup":"12 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 39 seconds"
},
"phmail":{
  "cpu":"0.8",
  "ram":"27.4",
  "hdd":"7.3",
  "osup":"2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds",
  "osstat":"0",
  "apachestat":"0",
  "apacheup":"5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 29 seconds",
  "sqlstat":"0",
  "sqlup":"5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 27 seconds",
  "emailstat":"0",
  "emailup":"2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds"
},
"ghweb":{
  "cpu":"0.4",
  "ram":"10.9",
  "hdd":"22.4",
  "osup":"2 days, 21 hours, 42 minutes and 17 seconds",
  "osstat":"0",
  "apachestat":"0",
  "apacheup":"2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 23 seconds",
  "sqlstat":"0",
  "sqlup":"2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 22 seconds"
},
"ghdbm":{
  "cpu":"0.5",
  "ram":"26.3",
  "hdd":"6.0",
  "osup":"2 days, 20 hours, 51 minutes and 58 seconds",
  "osstat":"0",
  "apachestat":"0",
  "apacheup":"103 days, 2 hours, 53 minutes and 50 seconds",
  "sqlstat":"0",
  "sqlup":"109 days, 21 hours, 3 minutes and 0 seconds"
   }
}
```

and im trying to loop on it and get the value that I want.

```
success: function(response){
    $.each(response.phweb, function(index, value){
        alert(value.cpu);
    });
}
```

but it gives me 'undefine'. Any ideas, help, clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over first object from the json, that doesn't contains any object only strings are there. Change `response.phweb` to `response`.

```js
var response = {
  "phweb": {
    "cpu": "34.8",
    "ram": "30.5",
    "hdd": "42.9",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 45 minutes and 28 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "32 days, 23 hours, 49 minutes and 13 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "13305410"
  },
  "phdbm": {
    "cpu": "14.7",
    "ram": "10.8",
    "hdd": "23.7",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 46 minutes and 15 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "103 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 53 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "12 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 39 seconds"
  },
  "phmail": {
    "cpu": "0.8",
    "ram": "27.4",
    "hdd": "7.3",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 29 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 27 seconds",
    "emailstat": "0",
    "emailup": "2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds"
  },
  "ghweb": {
    "cpu": "0.4",
    "ram": "10.9",
    "hdd": "22.4",
    "osup": "2 days, 21 hours, 42 minutes and 17 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 23 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 22 seconds"
  },
  "ghdbm": {
    "cpu": "0.5",
    "ram": "26.3",
    "hdd": "6.0",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 51 minutes and 58 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "103 days, 2 hours, 53 minutes and 50 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "109 days, 21 hours, 3 minutes and 0 seconds"
  }
};

$.each(response, function(index, value) {
  alert(value.cpu);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to get `cpu` value from `phweb`, then there is no need of `$.each()~ just use`response.phweb.cpu`

```js
var response = {
  "phweb": {
    "cpu": "34.8",
    "ram": "30.5",
    "hdd": "42.9",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 45 minutes and 28 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "32 days, 23 hours, 49 minutes and 13 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "13305410"
  },
  "phdbm": {
    "cpu": "14.7",
    "ram": "10.8",
    "hdd": "23.7",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 46 minutes and 15 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "103 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 53 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "12 days, 2 hours, 23 minutes and 39 seconds"
  },
  "phmail": {
    "cpu": "0.8",
    "ram": "27.4",
    "hdd": "7.3",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 29 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "5 days, 3 hours, 54 minutes and 27 seconds",
    "emailstat": "0",
    "emailup": "2 days, 20 hours, 39 minutes and 29 seconds"
  },
  "ghweb": {
    "cpu": "0.4",
    "ram": "10.9",
    "hdd": "22.4",
    "osup": "2 days, 21 hours, 42 minutes and 17 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 23 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "2 days, 23 hours, 44 minutes and 22 seconds"
  },
  "ghdbm": {
    "cpu": "0.5",
    "ram": "26.3",
    "hdd": "6.0",
    "osup": "2 days, 20 hours, 51 minutes and 58 seconds",
    "osstat": "0",
    "apachestat": "0",
    "apacheup": "103 days, 2 hours, 53 minutes and 50 seconds",
    "sqlstat": "0",
    "sqlup": "109 days, 21 hours, 3 minutes and 0 seconds"
  }
};
 
alert(response.phweb.cpu);
```

Comment: nice, but I want to get only the 'cpu' value from 'phweb', any ideas? I dont want too loop unto all of the 'cpu' value.

Comment: @CodeDemon : then just use `response.phweb.cpu`

Comment: and how about I want to loop only in the 'phweb' ang get its 'cpu' value as well as other specific value within that json array?

Comment: @CodeDemon : there is no need to loop , just you need to use `response.phweb.cpu`

Comment: @CodeDemon if you want to then `$.each(response.phweb, function(index, value){
     if(index=='cpu){ alert(value);}
    });`

Answer (score 1):

for example:-

```
$.each(response.phweb, function(index,value){
          console.log(index + " : " + value);
         //alert(index.cpu);
        });
```